# Space between algorithm and text

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e

I'm using `algorithm2e` to write algorithms. I can't figure out how to place some space (a line would be enough) between my text and the `algorithm` environment above and below after the caption. here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}
\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:
%space needed
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<niter)$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
%space needed
\noindent Moreover some text:
\end{document}
```

I need to use `[H]` instead of `[h]` otherwise it place it after the "Moreover".

Answer (score 4):

Just add a `center` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}

\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:
\begin{center}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<\mathit{niter})$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{center}
Moreover some text:

\end{document}
```

Or “abuse” a math display (this ensures no page break can happen before the algorithm)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}

\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:
\[
\begin{minipage}{\displaywidth}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<\mathit{niter})$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{minipage}
\]
Moreover some text:

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, if the algorithm needs to have a caption, it can be made a floating object. Using a cross reference makes the text independent of the final position of the float.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}

\begin{document}

We can finally state the algorithm, displayed as Algorithm~\ref{algo:toa}.

\begin{algorithm}[htp]
\While{$(k<\mathit{niter})$}{
 do something
}
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm\label{algo:toa}}
\end{algorithm}

Moreover some text:

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace the lines with comments between the text and the algorithm by blank lines and use `\SetAlgoSkip{bigskip}` before the algorithm or in preamble.

---

### Explanation

[`algorithm2e`](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf#page=30) provides `\SetAlgoSkip` to add spaces before **and** after the algorithm.

There are four possibilities:

> - `\SetAlgoSkip{}` for no extra vertical skip
> - `\SetAlgoSkip{smallskip}` to act as the default behaviour
> - `\SetAlgoSkip{medskip}` to have a bigger skip
> - `\SetAlgoSkip{bigskip}` to have the bigger skip

You can also define a command with a custom skip and pass its name (without `\`) to `\SetAlgoSkip`.

### Examples

Using `\SetAlgoSkip{bigskip}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain]{caption}
   
\SetAlgoSkip{bigskip} % <------ added

\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<niter)$}{
 do something
 }
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent Moreover some text:
\end{document}
```

[image: With bigskip]

---

Using custom spacing (defining new command):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain]{caption}
   
\newcommand{\SkipBeforeAndAfter}{\vspace{1cm}}  % <------ added

\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:

\SetAlgoSkip{SkipBeforeAndAfter} % <------ added (without \)
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<niter)$}{
 do something
 }
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent Moreover some text:
\end{document}
```

[image: Custom spacing]

### Extra

If you want to define different spaces for before and after the algorithm, one possibility is to do the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage[font={small,it}]{caption}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
  justification=justified,
  format=plain]{caption}
   
\usepackage{etoolbox}% <---- needed for this solution
\providetoggle{beginFlag}
\settoggle{beginFlag}{true}
\newcommand{\SkipBeforeAndAfter}{%
    \iftoggle{beginFlag}{%
        \settoggle{beginFlag}{false}%
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% <---- initial space (before)
    }{%
        \settoggle{beginFlag}{true}%
        \vspace{3\baselineskip}% <---- final space (after)
    }%
}
    
\SetAlgoSkip{SkipBeforeAndAfter}

\begin{document}
We can finally state the algorithm:

\begin{algorithm}[H]
\While{$(k<niter)$}{
 do something
 }
\caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent Moreover some text:
\end{document}
```

[image: extra]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what kind of space you're after exactly, you have some options.

1. Leave a blank line between the text and the `algorithm`. This will insert a `\parskip`:

   ```
   We can finally state the algorithm:

   \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \While{$(k < n)$}{
       do something
     }
     \caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
   \end{algorithm}

   \noindent Moreover some text:
   ```
2. Manually insert a `\vspace{<len>}` between the text and the `algorithm`, *ensuring* that you are in vertical mode. That is, also leave a blank line between the two or insert an explicit `\par`.

   ```
   \noindent
   We can finally state the algorithm:

   \vspace{\baselineskip}% Insert a blank line

   \begin{algorithm}[H]
     \While{$(k < n)$}{
       do something
     }
     \caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
   \end{algorithm}

   \vspace{\baselineskip}% Insert a blank line

   \noindent Moreover some text:
   ```
3. Automate (2) using [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ):

   ```
   \usepackage{environ}

   \let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
   \let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm

   \RenewEnviron{algorithm}[1][htbp]{%
     \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
     \begin{oldalgorithm}[#1]
       \BODY
     \end{oldalgorithm}
     \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
     \ignorespacesafterend
   }
   ```

Using `[H]` and a blank line (or a vertical skip) may cause the text to separate from the `algorithm` around a page/column break.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,
   justification=justified,
   format=plain]{caption}

\usepackage{environ}

\let\oldalgorithm\algorithm
\let\endoldalgorithm\endalgorithm

\RenewEnviron{algorithm}[1][htbp]{%
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \begin{oldalgorithm}[#1]
    \BODY
  \end{oldalgorithm}
  \par\vspace{\baselineskip}
  \ignorespacesafterend
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
We can finally state the algorithm:

\vspace{\baselineskip}% Insert a blank line

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \While{$(k < n)$}{
    do something
  }
  \caption{Topology optimization algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent Moreover some text:

\end{document}
```